# Extracting a max date or another date

Tags: t-sql

Currently I have the following query:

```
select t.datereceived
from t
inner join c on c.conditionid = t.conditionid
where t.active = 'Y' 
and c.usecondition = 'Y' 
and t.recordid = 123
order by t.received desc
```

that brings back

```
datereceived
2019-11-20 15:19:18.313
2009-10-14 22:37:50.217
2000-01-01 00:00:00.000
2000-01-01 00:00:00.000
2000-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

I need to return the max date. However, I need to identify if the date 2000-01-01 is in the results.

Using the above data as the example, I am stumped on how to modify my query to return one row with either 2019-11-20, or 2000-01-01.

Note: Table t is about 150 million rows, indexed on recordid. Table c is less than 5k rows.The above query conditions will bring back less than 100 rows for a given recordid. In sample data above I left out an additional 10 rows of 2000-01-01 data.

I hope I've provided enough info for some sage advice. Thanks.

Comment: is '2000-01-01' the min date? if so, can take both the min and the max, chec whether the min value is your special value, and if not, take the max value. see the CASE statement for more info on how this can be done. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: OR take the COUNT of the number of times the special date appears in the grouping, and if 0, then take max date, otherwise take special date.

Comment: @Jeremy Tried min and max, and it works fine, and it's very quick. Thanks. I didn't consider using min and max because I thought it would take too long. My very bad for not even trying that.